# Sendgrid adding email to list, getting bad request in grails

Tags: grails, sendgrid, httpbuilder

I am trying to use following code to send request to sendgrid for adding emails to list, but i always keep getting 404 : Bad request.

```
def chttps = new HTTPBuilder('https://api.sendgrid.com/api/newsletter/lists/email/add.json?&api_user=myUser&api_key=myKey')

    chttps.request( Method.POST, ContentType.JSON ) { req ->
        headers.'Content-Type' = 'application/json'
        body = [
            list : 'testlist',
            data : [email : '123Ex@exm.pl', name : '123Ex' ]
        ]

        response.success = { resp, json ->
            // response handling here
        }
        // handler for any failure status code:

    }
```

Following is the error i get:

    `Bad Request. Stacktrace follows:
    groovyx.net.http.HttpResponseException: Bad Request
    at groovyx.net.http.HTTPBuilder.defaultFailureHandler(HTTPBuilder.java:609)
    at groovyx.net.http.HTTPBuilder.doRequest(HTTPBuilder.java:475)
     at groovyx.net.http.HTTPBuilder.doRequest(HTTPBuilder.java:417)
     at groovyx.net.http.HTTPBuilder.request(HTTPBuilder.java:366)
    at com.farmfresh.brandywine.erp.SendGridService$$EOc3vKl8.addEmailsToRecipientList(SendGridService.groovy:16)
    at com.farmfresh.brandywine.erp.CustomerController$_closure5$$EOc3pEvI.doCall(CustomerController.groovy:106)
    at org.zkoss.zk.grails.web.ZKGrailsPageFilter.obtainContent(ZKGrailsPageFilter.java:238)
    at org.zkoss.zk.grails.web.ZKGrailsPageFilter.doFilter(ZKGrailsPageFilter.java:189)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:895)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:918)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)`

can't find what's wrong. Please help.

EDIT1:

So i tried using following code, and it works fine, but still cant specify list of emails in data section:

```
            def chttps = new HTTPBuilder('https://api.sendgrid.com/api/newsletter/lists/email/add.json?&api_user=myUser&api_key=myKey')
            def dataa = "list=testlist&data=%7B%22email%22%3A%22examuttample%40gmail.com%22%2C%22name%22%3A%22uttam%22%7D"
            chttps.post(  body: dataa
                            ) { resp ->
                            println "${resp}"
                         resp.headers.each {
                                println "${it.name} : ${it.value}"
                         }
                            println "${resp.data}"

                            println "http POST Success: ${resp.statusLine}"
                        }
```

For adding multiple emails in single request i tried putting following format:

```
data=%5B%7B%22email%22%3A+%22example1112%40gmail.com%22%2C%22name%22%3A+%22112example%22%7D%2C%7B%22email%22%3A+%22example2222%40gmail.com%22%2C%22name%22%3A+%22222example%22%7D%5D 
//encode for :: [{"email": "example1112@gmail.com","name": "112example"},{"email": "example2222@gmail.com","name": "222example"}]
```

but i keep getting following exception, is there a way around this to add multiple emails.

```
    groovyx.net.http.HttpResponseException: Internal Server Error
at groovyx.net.http.HTTPBuilder.defaultFailureHandler(HTTPBuilder.java:642)
at groovyx.net.http.HTTPBuilder$1.handleResponse(HTTPBuilder.java:494)
at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:1070)
at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:1044)
at groovyx.net.http.HTTPBuilder.doRequest(HTTPBuilder.java:506)
at groovyx.net.http.HTTPBuilder.post(HTTPBuilder.java:343)
at com.farmfresh.brandywine.erp.SendGridService$$EOc9RNxT.addEmailsToRecipientList(SendGridService.groovy:40)
at com.farmfresh.brandywine.erp.CustomerController$_closure5$$EOc9QqKy.doCall(CustomerController.groovy:109)
at org.zkoss.zk.grails.web.ZKGrailsPageFilter.obtainContent(ZKGrailsPageFilter.java:238)
at org.zkoss.zk.grails.web.ZKGrailsPageFilter.doFilter(ZKGrailsPageFilter.java:189)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:895)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:918)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Solved it, turns out json arrays are not acceptable by server instead it accepts multiple "data[]" elements in query string, so all you need to do is call this:

```
sendgrid.com/api/newsletter/lists/email/add.json?list=testlist&data[]={"email"+%3A+"123Ex1%40exm.pl"%2C+"name"+%3A+"123Ex1"}&data[]={"email"+%3A+"123Ex2%40exm.pl"%2C+"name"+%3A+"123Ex2"}&api_user=myUser&api_key=myKey
```

Hope this helps someone else.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are trying to post a JSON payload. The SendGrid API currently doesn't support JSON payloads, so you need to send your payload as POST data.

Comment: thanx for the tip, i encoded the data section and updated the code according to it(Please have a look at edit in question), but still i am not able to add more than one email to request.I'll vote up if i could but i need reputation